# REST API filter with field whose value is calculated based on other fields dynamically

Tags: spring-boot, rest

I have a REST service(Springboot) that provides basic CRUD for resources in DB. For instance, a resource named **virtual-machines**.

The response body of **GET** virtual-machines looks like this:

```
{
    "vmName": "123",
    "vmDisks": [
        {
            "disk1": {"diskSize": 123},
            "disk2": {"diskSize": 234}
        }
    ],
    "totalSize" : 357
}
```

I want to filter virtual-machine whose totalSize is larger than 300.

`/api/virtual-machines?filter="totalSize lt 300"`

However, the field **`totalSize`** is not persistently stored in DB(Calculated dynamically based on `diskSize` field in REST layer). Filtering fields in DB can be easily achieved by transmitting the filter into DB, and pagination can be handled by DB at the same time.

For this calculated field - `totalSize`, I have no idea how to support the filtering and ordering. Obviously, I can not get all the resources in memory and do the filtering and ordering on this special field with pagination manually.

I appreciate your reply.

Comment: As you don't want to do such filtering in memory then how are you calculating totalSize field?

Comment: The totalSize can be calculated for each VM. However, to support filter and order, it looks like I have to load all the VMs in the memory which is not acceptable for me.

Comment: First, REST isn't a direct mapping of your domain/DB model to resources! Second, you are not doing REST but plain RPC with a proprietary message format, custom logic and probably plenty of further things Fielding would disagree with. Why do you need the "REST layer" to start with? Why don't you expose your DB directly? Why do you need a further level of abstraction and complexity if you just pass through your domain or DB model? Almost all DBs have a sophisticated rights management and support custom views for selected users

Comment: one workaround which i can think of is apply Pagination at Database for without totalSize field and then apply the logic to populate the totalSize field.
Then apply filter on totalSize field and keep the filtered result in memory. Then repeat the process till all the DB records are processed. Then apply Pagination on the In-Memory filtered List and return.